# Categorical Logic

Tags: logic

Which of the four basic categorical forms are consistent with one another?

A-claim (universal affirmative): All S is P / All S are P

E-claim (universal negative): No S is P / No S are P

I-claim (particular affirmative): Some S is P / Some S are P

O-claim (particular negative): Some S is not P / Some S are not P

Comment: Hi, welcome to PSE. What does "consistent with one another" mean?

Comment: The answer is the following are consistent sets: {A, I} , {E, O}, {I,O} . The inconsistent sets are {E, I} and {A, O}. The contradictory set is {A, E}. This is almost definitely homework...

Comment: See [Square of Opposition](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/square/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, "inconsistent" is a little ambiguous. I've just completed an online quiz whose explanation says the following: "inconsistent" means that there is no possible way for both statements to be true at the same time.

In this vein, A and E are NOT inconsistent with each other. If there is no single object P in existence, then for any attribute Q it will be both true that (i) all Ps are Q (simply because there is no P that is not Q) and (ii) that no Ps are Q (well, because there are no Ps at all).

Comment: I don't know any other definition of `inconsistent', so I'm not sure there's any ambiguity.

Comment: There's an ambiguity about your ambiguity interestingly enough. I read this and at first thought "this makes sense", then I thought about whether it's possible for an A claim to apply to an empty set. Turns out the answer *classically* was **no**. The issue is called "existential assumption" (http://academic.csuohio.edu/polen/LC10_WebHelp/4/existential.htm http://home.sbu.edu/rhughes/Symbolic%20Logic/logic_of_categories.htm  http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01445349608837261  http://www.jstor.org/stable/20009486?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)